# Solidity Warning

Tags: solidity

I want to know what's wrong with my function, 'cause Visual Studio Code give me warning :

> function state mutability can be restricted to view

this is my function :

```
  function verifyVote(address pers) public returns (uint){

    for (uint i = 0; i < personne.length; i++){
        if (pers == personne[i].own) {
            if (personne[i].isVoted == true){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Since your function doesn't modify any state in the contract, it can be changes to a `view` function. VS code is suggesting a best practice and your code will compile even without this. For more information about function state mutability, refer solidity documentation at https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#view-functions

Answer (score 3):

Your function doesn't modify the state, so it can be declared as a `view` function.

From the [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#view-functions):

> Functions can be declared `view` in which case they promise not to
>   modify the state.

```
function verifyVote(address pers) public view returns (uint){
    for (uint i = 0; i < personne.length; i++){
        if (pers == personne[i].own) {
            if (personne[i].isVoted == true){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your contract contains a state variable `personne[]`.

Your function `verifyVote()` **only reads** values from your contract storage, by looping through each elements of the `personne[]` array. **It does not modify the values**.

From the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#view-functions)

> Functions can be declared view in which case they promise not to modify the state.

- `view` = read, <del>write</del>
- `pure` = <del>read</del>, <del>write</del>
- No specifier = read, write

So the `view` specifier ensures that your function is restricted to **read-only**.

Comment: There is, because calling this function from an off-chain script requires signing and sending a transaction, and then paying gas fee for it to be executed. In addition to that, the value returned to the off-chain is going to be the receipt of that transaction, rather than the `uint` intended by the author. And in order to make that value available for the off-chain script, the author will need to emit it in an event (which will furthermore increase the gas cost). So in short, there is a lot wrong in not specifying `pure` or `view` where possible.

Comment: @goodvibration I am jumping on your last sentence : `So in short, there is a lot wrong in not specifying pure or view where possible.`.
Emiting an event is an operation that modifies the state. Therefore, the function cannot be declared as `view` if it emits an event.
So does that mean that the function should have "no specifier" if the aim is to make the value available to an off-chain script (via the event log) ?

Comment: On the contrary, the function should be declared `view`, so that the off-chain script will be able to obtain the returned value. Emitting the returned value in an event should be reserved only to cases where the function **cannot** be declared `view` (AND - the returned value is expected to be required by an off-chain script).